How to Converge the CUTOFF and REL_CUTOFF
I'm doing the "How to Converge the CUTOFF and REL_CUTOFF" tutorial, but I can't get the results after cutoff_run.sh using .ssmp . The calculation cashes and end with the message below:
 ===== Routine Calling Stack =====

            3 scf_env_do_scf
            2 qs_energies
            1 CP2K

I tried to run using the script (cutoff_run.sh) and also running in each directory individually. Getting the same result.
Can anyone help me with this problem?

The traceback you show doesnt provide the error message. Please provide more info from the output file so we can help.

@Inna, welcome to MatterModeling! I agree it would be helpful for us to see more of the error trace and/or input files to diagnose this problem.

Hi, thank you for your time...I have already installed the psmp version and it works well.
